# Incorrect coordinates when converting shapefile with shp2pgsql

Tags: coordinates, gis, shapefile, coordinate-systems, geography

I have a shapefile of NYS legislative districts that seems to be formatted in the GCS_North_American_1983 coordinate system, and I want to put this in a postgres database in latitude/longitude format. I'm using shp2pgsql and PostGIS but can't seem to figure out what parameters to use to get it to work correctly.

I've tried `shp2pgsql -I -s 4269 NYS-Assembly-Districts.shp assembly_districts` but the lat/long values are in the hundreds of thousands (retrieved using `select st_x(st_centroid(geom)), st_y(st_centroid(geom)) from assembly_districts;` in pgsql). Some information suggests that `-s` takes a `from_srid` and `to_srid` but I can't figure out what either of these are supposed to be.

The information in the .prj file is `PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_18N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-75.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell shp2pgsql both the current and the new SRID, if you want to transform the data during import.

So:

`shp2pgsql -I -s 4269:4326 NYS-Assembly-Districts.shp assembly_districts`

where the 4326 is the SRID for unprojected latitude/longitude.

Alternatively, transform it first using something like `gdalwarp`, and then import using shp2pgql. This way you could check it quickly to make sure it's good before it hits the database.